# Hadoop Map Reduce Program Key and Value Passing

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to learn hadoop.

I have the following file downloaded from free large data set websites. I made it short for my sample testing. This is the small file.

```
"CAMIS","DBA","BORO","BUILDING","STREET","ZIPCODE","PHONE","CUISINECODE","INSPDATE","ACTION","VIOLCODE","SCORE","CURRENTGRADE","GRADEDATE","RECORDDATE"
"40280083","INTERCONTINENTAL THE BARCLAY","1","111       ","EAST   48 STREET                                                                                    ","10017","2129063134","03","2014-02-07 00:00:00","D","10F","4","A","2014-02-07 00:00:00","2014-04-24 06:01:04.920000000"
"40356649","REGINA CATERERS","3","6409","11 AVENUE","11219","7182560829","03","2013-07-30 00:00:00","D","08A","12","A","2013-07-30 00:00:00","2014-04-24 06:01:04.920000000"
"40356649","REGINA CATERERS","3","6409","11 AVENUE","11219","7182560829","03","2013-07-30 00:00:00","D","08B","12","A","2013-07-30 00:00:00","2014-04-24 06:01:04.920000000"
"40356731","TASTE THE TROPICS ICE CREAM","3","1839      ","NOSTRAND AVENUE                                                                                     ","11226","7188560821","43","2013-07-10 00:00:00","D","06C","8","A","2013-07-10 00:00:00","2014-04-24 06:01:04.920000000"
"40356731","TASTE THE TROPICS ICE CREAM","3","1839      ","NOSTRAND AVENUE                                                                                     ","11226","7188560821","43","2013-07-10 00:00:00","D","10B","8","A","2013-07-10 00:00:00","2014-04-24 06:01:04.920000000"
"40357217","WILD ASIA","2","2300","SOUTHERN BOULEVARD","10460","7182207846","03","2013-06-19 00:00:00","D","10B","4","A","2013-06-19 00:00:00","2014-04-24 06:01:04.920000000"
"40360045","SEUDA FOODS","3","705       ","KINGS HIGHWAY                                                                                       ","11223","7183751500","50","2013-10-10 00:00:00","D","08C","13","A","2013-10-10 00:00:00","2014-04-24 06:01:04.920000000"
"40361521","GLORIOUS FOOD","1","522","EAST   74 STREET","10021","2127372140","03","2013-12-19 00:00:00","U","08A","16","B","2013-12-19 00:00:00","2014-04-24 06:01:04.920000000"
"40362098","HARRIET'S KITCHEN","1","502","AMSTERDAM AVENUE","10024","2127210045","18","2014-03-04 00:00:00","U","10F","13","A","2014-03-04 00:00:00","2014-04-24 06:01:04.920000000"
"40361322","CARVEL ICE CREAM","4","265-15    ","HILLSIDE AVENUE                                   ","11004","7183430392","43","2013-09-18 00:00:00","D","08A","10","A","2013-09-18 00:00:00","2014-04-24 06:01:04.920000000"
"40361708","BULLY'S DELI","1","759       ","BROADWAY                                                                                            ","10003","2122549755","27","2014-01-21 00:00:00","D","10F","12","A","2014-01-21 00:00:00","2014-04-24 06:01:04.920000000"
"40362098","HARRIET'S KITCHEN","1","502","AMSTERDAM AVENUE","10024","2127210045","18","2014-03-04 00:00:00","U","04N","13","A","2014-03-04 00:00:00","2014-04-24 06:01:04.920000000"
"40362274","ANGELIKA FILM CENTER","1","18","WEST HOUSTON STREET","10012","2129952570","03","2014-04-03 00:00:00","D","06D","9","A","2014-04-03 00:00:00","2014-04-24 06:01:04.920000000"
"40362715","THE COUNTRY CAFE","1","60","WALL STREET","10005","3474279132","83","2013-09-18 00:00:00","D","10B","13","A","2013-09-18 00:00:00","2014-04-24 06:01:04.920000000"
"40362869","SHASHEMENE INT'L RESTAURA","3","195","EAST   56 STREET","11203","3474300871","17","2013-05-08 00:00:00","D","10B","7","A","2013-05-08 00:00:00","2014-04-24 06:01:04.920000000"
"40363021","DOWNTOWN DELI","1","107","CHURCH STREET","10007","2122332911","03","2014-02-26 00:00:00","D","10B","9","A","2014-02-26 00:00:00","2014-04-24 06:01:04.920000000"
"40362432","HO MEI RESTAURANT","4","103-05","37 AVENUE","11368","7187796903","20","2014-04-21 00:00:00","D","06C","10","A","2014-04-21 00:00:00","2014-04-24 06:01:04.920000000"
"40362869","SHASHEMENE INT'L RESTAURA","3","195","EAST   56 STREET","11203","3474300871","17","2013-05-08 00:00:00","D","10F","7","A","2013-05-08 00:00:00","2014-04-24 06:01:04.920000000"
"40363117","MEJLANDER & MULGANNON","3","7615","5 AVENUE","11209","7182386666","03","2013-10-24 00:00:00","D","02G","11","A","2013-10-24 00:00:00","2014-04-24 06:01:04.920000000"
"40363289","HAPPY GARDEN","2","1236      ","238 SPOFFORD AVE                                                                                    ","10474","7186171818","20","2013-12-30 00:00:00","D","10F","8","A","2013-12-30 00:00:00","2014-04-24 06:01:04.920000000"
"40363644","DOMINO'S PIZZA","1","464","3 AVENUE","10016","2125450200","62","2014-03-06 00:00:00","D","08A","11","A","2014-03-06 00:00:00","2014-04-24 06:01:04.920000000"
"30191841","DJ REYNOLDS PUB AND RESTAURANT","1","351       ","WEST   57 STREET                                  ","10019","2122452912","03","2013-07-22 00:00:00","D","10B","11","A","2013-07-22 00:00:00","2014-04-24 06:01:04.920000000"
"40280083","INTERCONTINENTAL THE BARCLAY","1","111       ","EAST   48 STREET                                                                                    ","10017","2129063134","03","2014-02-07 00:00:00","D","10B","4","A","2014-02-07 00:00:00","2014-04-24 06:01:04.920000000"
"40356442","KOSHER ISLAND","5","2206","VICTORY BOULEVARD","10314","7186985800","50","2013-04-04 00:00:00","D","10F","12","A","2013-04-04 00:00:00","2014-04-24 06:01:04.920000000"
"40356483","WILKEN'S FINE FOOD","3","7114      ","AVENUE U                        ","11234","7184443838","27","2014-01-14 00:00:00","D","10B","10","A","2014-01-14 00:00:00","2014-04-24 06:01:04.920000000"
```

File is about some inspection in restaurants.

You can see there is CUISINECODE. Values of it ranges from "00" to some value or can be any value. There will be many restaurants have the same CUISINECODE.

I just want to display the number of restaurants in each cusinecode.

This is my MapReducer Program

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;

public class RestaurantInspection {

    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
                throws IOException {

            String line = value.toString();

            if (line.startsWith("\"CAMIS\",")) {
                // Line is the header, ignore it
                return;
            }
            List<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();
            String[] tokens = line.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
            if (tokens.length != 15) {
                // Line isn't the correct number of columns or formatted properly
                return;
            }
            for(String t : tokens) {
                columns.add(t.replaceAll("\"", ""));
            }

            int cusineCode = Integer.parseInt(columns.get(7));
            String violations = columns.get(9) + " --- " + columns.get(10);
            value.set(violations);
            output.collect(value, new IntWritable(cusineCode));

        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements
            Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

        @Override
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values,
                OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
                throws IOException {

            int sum = 0;
            while (values.hasNext()) {
                sum += values.next().get();
            }

            output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JobConf conf = new JobConf(RestaurantInspection.class);
        conf.setJobName("Restaurent Inspection");

        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

        JobClient.runJob(conf);

    }
}
```

I am using **hadoop 1.2.1**. I copied the above code from WordCount Example and just changed few lines.

When I run the above code in hadoop I am getting following lines for the same file I given above

```
D --- 02G   3
D --- 06C   63
D --- 06D   3
D --- 08A   108
D --- 08B   3
D --- 08C   50
D --- 10B   182
D --- 10F   117
U --- 04N   18
U --- 08A   3
U --- 10F   18
```

That was just a test. I am not getting any logic of how to write the code to get the desired output. I am expecting the following output for the above file.

```
01 -- 1
03 -- 9
43 -- 3
50 -- 2
18 -- 2
27 -- 2
83 -- 1
17 -- 2
20 -- 2
62 -- 1
```

By this, I think I can learn hadoop and map reduce.

So how to write the code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need key to be CUISINECODE. 
`String cusineCode = columns.get(7);
 output.collect(new Text(cusineCode), new IntWritable(1));`

This will do the job for you.

Comment: Sorry, Can you tell me why we pass 1 and cuisinecode as key? Or u have any link that explains the code of wordcount or any example?